# Как защитить исходный код для Телегарм-бота?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, лицензирование, opensource, авторские-права

Написал простого Телеграм-бота на Node.js для решения локальной городской проблемы с доставкой информации. Проект чисто волонтерский, поэтому не хотелось бы, чтобы кто-то использовал код в коммерческих целях.
Куда лучше всего разместить проект, на GitHub? Какую copyleft лицензию использовать? Требование к лицензии просты: можно смотреть, редактировать, распространять модификации, ссылаясь на авторский проект, но нельзя использовать в коммерческих целях.
Как учитывать модули, которые я использую? Прочитать их лицензии и выполнить требования?

Answer (score 3):

Что касается размещения репозитория с исходным кодом, то [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) позволяет иметь как публичные, так и приватные репозитории [бесплатно](https://bitbucket.org/product/pricing?tab=cloud) для небольших команд (до 5 человек). [GitHub](https://github.com/pricing) бесплатно размещает только публичные репозитории.

Если же вы хотите иметь именно публичный репозиторий и защитить код от некорректно переиспользования, то следует детально ознакомиться с политиками лицензирования, например в [этой статье](https://habr.com/post/243091/).

Answer (score -1):

Список активных Opensource/Free software лицензий

- Apache License 2.0
- GNU General Public License v3.0
- MIT License
- BSD 2-Clause "Simplified" License
- BSD 3-Clause "New" or "Revised" License
- Eclipse Public License 2.0
- GNU Affero General Public License v3.0
- GNU General Public License v2.0
- GNU Lesser General Public License v2.1
- GNU Lesser General Public License v3.0
- Mozilla Public License 2.0

**Сылки**

- https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html
- https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
- https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
- https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
- https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/MPL/
- https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html